# Create YAML file from String

Tags: java, yaml

My Pebble template outputs a String and I wanted this String to save as YAML file without using Spring Boot. The references I see in Google either dumps the Object or Map to YAML file. Is it possible to dump a String to YAML?

Just to add : the String from Pebble template is in YAML format.

Thanks

Comment: If the String is already in YAML format, just write it to a file as-is.

Comment: If the file is saved as-is how do we validate/parse if the String is in correct YAML format? I tried converting String to ObjectMapper and to convert as JSON node so that I can dump as YAML, I am getting com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token '': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Comment: You did say that you *know* the string is in YAML format. If you want to *test* whether the string is a valid YAML character stream, why are you loading it as JSON? If the result of your test is that the input is *not* valid YAML, why is that a problem if the string not being valid YAML is an expected possibility? If you have a specific problem with a specific part of your code, you should edit your question to contain a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).